# Are there specific hours when Kiruna airport is open or is it open 24/7?

Tags: airports, sweden, opening-hours, krn

I'm going to be in Kiruna, Sweden. I will arrive to the town late and I have a flight at 6 am. It does not make sense to me to book hotel for a couple of hours.

Are there specific hours when Kiruna airport is open or is it open 24/7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't find a reference on the [airport's own web site](https://www.swedavia.com/kiruna/#gref), but from [this page](https://www.kirunalapland.se/en/travel-here/airplane/)

> The terminal at Kiruna Airport is open during the day. The terminal
>   **opens about an hour before the first flight** departure and **close about
>   30 minutes after the last flight** arrival. This means that the terminal
>   is closed during the night. Kiruna Airport doesn’t offer any
>   accommodation in direct connection with the airport.